# eth0 not enabled after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, upgrade, ethernet

I've upgraded my ubuntu 14 VM a few days ago (was about time) to 16.04 but now I ran into some trouble. Every time the VM reboots the eth0 link can't be enabled (from log):

```
Jan 31 16:50:11 hostname systemd[1]: Started ifup for eth0.
Jan 31 16:50:11 hostname sh[662]: ifup: interface eth0 already configured
Jan 31 17:42:00 hostname systemd[1]: Started ifup for eth0.
Jan 31 17:42:00 hostname sh[647]: ifup: interface eth0 already configured
```

(both reboots I did)

I have to manually run `ifdown`, then `ifup` again to get it working.
Before I did the upgrade everything was fine and I haven't changed anything myself in any networking related config. The address is statically configured to it can't be a dhcp problem either.
All other Ubuntu 16.04 VMs work fine on the same host.

Any ideas?

Thanks you!

Comment: If you are on the machine and type `sudo ifup -n eth0`, do you see any errors reported? (The `-n` means "take no action", so this will not affect your network).

Comment: currently I get `ifup: interface eth0 already configured` as result but I can't reboot it now, I use it for production.